# Выражение "заявить о том, что"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

По-моему, **заявить о том, что** что-то происходит, можно в полицию (в смысле подать заявление), а в остальных случаях следует **заявить, что** что-то происходит или **заявить о** происходящем. 
Но вот типичный пример от РИА НОВОСТИ:
"Ранее в Тегеране **заявили о том, что** Россия может пользоваться авиабазой в Хамадане до тех пор, пока в этом есть необходимость, подчеркивая, что на базе производится только дозаправка бомбардировщиков."
Неужели так правильно/допустимо говорить?

Comment: А почему нельзя  "заявить" в смысле "сделать публичное заявление о том... (подразумеваемом обстоятельстве, факте, решении, намерении, договоре, плане и т. п.)"? Чем это отличается от подачи куда-то заявления по поводу уже случившегося?

Comment: @Alex_under, пожалуй, вы правы, так можно говорить, но все же... Разница есть. Ведь "сделать заявление" стилистически сильнее, чем просто "заявить". В той же мере "заявить о том, что" отличается от  "заявить, что". Т.е. РИА НОВОСТИ сообщили, что  в Тегеране "сделали заявление". Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Я не знаю, в каком контексте это "заявили", но  по содержанию и "силе слова" предположил, что в ответ на высказанное какой-то страной неудовольствие было сделано публичное заявление о том (о принятом разрешительном решении на будущее), что России можно будет пользоваться аэродромом (чтобы недовольная сторона это услышала и приняла к сведению). Если неудовольствие высказывалось официально и с трибуны, то выражение "выступить с заявлением", думаю, подошло бы.

Answer (score 2):

Я как и вы нахожу предпочтительной формулировку: "Ранее в Тегеране заявили, **что**...", т.к. в данном случае они [власти Тегерана] заявили что-то, а не о чем-то по факту.